# JQuery change class when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to `JQuery`, I know this question is already answered in other posts but please help me on this,
How can i change the class of `<li>` tag if a link `<a>` is clicked?

```
<li class="link" id="home" >
   <a href="admin?main=home">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="link" id="flt" >
   <a href="admin?main=flt">FLT</a>
</li>
```

This is what i have tried so far:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Please explain me the answer, other posts that is similar to mine doesn't have that much detail so i really don't understand how they do that?

Comment: If you're clicking the `a` element, the page location will change so surely changing the class on the `li` is redundant? Unless you've got some code in place which makes an AJAX request on `a.click()`

Comment: If the links are navigating, it is useless since the page navigating to the new page will remove the class!

Comment: @epascarello your right i never thought of that. How can i resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the element, the actual click target is the `a` element whose default action is to navigate to the resource specified in the `href` property.

In this case you are registering the click event in the `li` event, this handler is getting triggered because of [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) where an event happening in a descendant element will get bubbled upto the document root.

So the solution here is to prevent the default action of the click event(in this case the navigation of the `a` element) by calling the [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/%27) on the event.

```
var $lis = $('li').click(function(e) {
    $lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: I tried to put on a script, but it doesn't work even I remove the resource on the link.

Comment: the `lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active")` will append a "active" to the class?

Comment: @user2785929 it removes the `active` class from `li` elements having that class

Comment: so basically this line `$(this).addClass('active');` will appen active to class so the class would be link.active? and `$lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active");` will turn it back to link class only? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: how can i save the class if i navigate to the url? the `e.preventDefault()` removes the ability of the link to navigate to the url so i removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following script. http://jsfiddle.net/czG8h/

```
$('.link a').click(function() {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

If you want to persist the active style across the page, then following code will do the trick for you:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace( /^.*\/([^/]*)/ , "$1");

        ///// Apply active class to selected page link
        $('.link a').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Comment: what does this line `$("li.active")` means?

Comment: This means li having class active. ie. <li class='active'></li> . The whole line means if there is any active li remove the active class from it.

Comment: seems like this approach doesn't work if the link has a resource, how would i resolve if there is a resource to go with? how would i get the last link selected? the part of the code i posted above is a page header which is included in all of those url in the links. They are sharing same page header

Comment: The `(document).ready` I'll put it on the header page? and the `$('.link a').each` I'll put on the page that the link will go to? correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use .closest to get to parent li and add the class active then use siblings to find other li and remove the class active, and use e.preventDefault() to prevent changing page.

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Saa5Z/)

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` stopped my link to navigate to other pages.

Comment: I see, i thought that was what you wanted, then you can remove e.preventDefault() @user2785929

Comment: If i remove the `e.preventDefault();` it doesn't save the class if it navigate to the url